# How to prompt the user for a number that ends in a specific decimal?

Tags: java

I need an input that ends in .20 or .45, and is also positive. Until the user enters a value that satisfies those conditions, it will keep prompting for a value. I know I need a for loop, but how do I write that specific decimal condition?

```
    System.out.println("Enter a positive value ending in .20 or .45)");
    double x = input.nextDouble();
    boolean xPos = x>0;
    boolean x20 = // This is what I don't understand
```

Comment: Have you tried to multiply and modulo by 100?

Comment: Or, read the data as a string then check `endsWith(".20")` for example?

Comment: Normally, do/while is used for that, not for.  You could also just read the input as String.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of capturing the input as a numeric value, utilize the *String* object.

The *[String#endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))* method will allow you to equate a suffix value.

And, the *[Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))* will return the *double* value, of a given *String* value.

```java
System.out.println("Enter a positive value ending in .20 or .45)");
String string = input.nextLine();
if (string.endsWith(".20") || string.endsWith(".45")) {
    double x = Double.parseDouble(string);
    
}
```

Comment: Definitely test `String`s, not `double`s, yes. But `if ((string.indexOf('-') < 0) && (string.endsWith(".20") || string.endsWith(".45"))`

Answer (score 0):

You convert the decimal to a String.

```java
System.out.println("Enter a positive value ending in .20 or .45)");
double x = input.nextDouble();
String x_str = String.valueOf(x);
String x_last3digs = x.substring(len(x_str)-3);
boolean xPos = x > 0;
boolean x20 = x_last3digs.equals(".20");
boolean x45 = x_last3digs.equals(".45");
```

To make this loop until you get a valid answer, do this:

```java
do {
    double x = input.nextDouble();
    String x_str = String.valueOf(x);
    String x_last3digs = x.substring(len(x_str)-3);
    boolean xPos = x > 0;
    boolean x20 = x_last3digs.equals(".20");
    boolean x45 = x_last3digs.equals(".45");
} while (!x20 && !x45)
```

Comment: This code has compile-errors and basic bugs. And even if those were fixed . . . this is really the wrong approach. This check should be performed before converting the input to a `double`, rather than trying to convert the `double` back to a String to perform the check, because the conversion to `double` is a lossy one: the values of interest can't be represented exactly as floating-point numbers, and also, floating-point numbers don't care about trailing zeros (since those don't affect the numeric value).